# Can't run android jni app in eclipse with genymotion

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface, genymotion

I have used many tutorials to start with android and jni. My last was [this step by step tutorial](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/). I went through all the steps. But when I run it, application stoped. I used genymotion

1. I create Android app "HelloTest"
2. Create jni folder in the root of App: /home/nikolay/workspace/HelloTest/jni
3. Create in jni folder Android.mk file:

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_MODULE    := hello
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.cpp
   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```
4. Create in jni folder file hello.cpp

   ```
   #include <jni.h>
   jint Java_com_nikolay_hellotest_MainActivity(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis, jint a) {
   return a*a;
   ```

   }
5. Open terminal and go to my project folder, and successful run ndk-build:

   ```
   [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: hello <= hello.cpp
   [armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
   [armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libhello.so
   [armeabi] Install        : libhello.so => libs/armeabi/libhello.so
   ```
6. Add some code to MainActivity:

   ```
   package com.nikolay.hellotest;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.ActionBar;
   import android.app.Fragment;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.os.Build;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     // load the library - name matches jni/Android.mk 
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("hello");
   }
   // declare the native code function - must match hello.cpp
   public native int getIntValue(int val);

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
   }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
   // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
   // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
   int id = item.getItemId();
   if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
       return true;
   }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }

   /**
    * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
    */
   public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

   public PlaceholderFragment() {
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
               false);

       TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       tv.setText(Integer.toString(new MainActivity().getIntValue(24)));

       return rootView;
   }
   }
   }
   ```

was added:

```
    static {
       System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }
    // declare the native code function - must match hello.cpp
    public native int getIntValue(int val);
```

and

```
     TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(new MainActivity().getIntValue(24)));
```

I can't understand what's wrong. Appreciate any help.

Comment: maybe your genymotion installation is x86 not arm ...

Comment: how to check it? earlier I received an error **Error INSTALL FAILED CPU ABI INCOMPATIBLE** and make like [link] (http://www.tushroy.com/2014/01/android-ndk-development-genymotion-emulator.html)

Comment: You aren't going to be able to run an arm library on an x86 system, at least not without some kind of binary translation layer.  Realistically, it is generally best to test on a physical device - though an emulator can be useful for some edge cases where you need a different android version, a rooted device, or to simulate the external environment.  If you really want to use an x86 emulator, then add that to your list of ABIs to build for.

Comment: Thank you for help. But I can't use physical device now. And, excuse me, I don't really understand, what does mean "add x86 emulator to your list of ADIs to build for"?

Answer (score 2):

modify | add you Application.mk in jni folder "APP_ABI := x86"